# Uso de return new static y return $this en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un código  escrito en el paradigma de la POO en PHP, del modo siguiente

```
<?php

class Person
{
    protected static $type = NULL;
    protected static $name;
    public static function  userType($type)
    {
        return new static;
    }

    public static function myName($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Intentado aclaro el encadenamiento de métodos que están contenidos en una clase; del modo siguiente

```
echo Person::userType("administrador")->myName("alfa");
```

Sin embargo no termino de comprender la intención de uso de `return new static`

Mi punto de partida para empezar a estudiar, ha sido la documentación de PHP; en este apartado

- [documentación PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#114005)

He comprobado, en vez de utilizar métodos `estáticos`, crear la instancia de la clase a través de un objeto del modo siguiente

```
<?php

class Person
{
    protected $type = NULL;
    protected $name;
    public function  userType($type)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function myName($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
}

$object = new Person();

echo $object->userType("administrador")->myName("alfa");
```

En ambos casos no necesito al último método indicarle un retorno del ámbito de la clase con `$this` o hacer un retorno de este tipo `return new static`

Entonces las dudas son:

- ¿Por qué se retorna lo antes mencionado en cada ejemplo?

  - `return $this`
  - `return new static`
- ¿Cómo hacer para que en cada ejemplo, el primer método `userType` pueda retornar algo sin que interfiera con el retorno propio de `$this`? por que yo en el método `userType` deseo retornar el tipo de usuario pero con la keyword `return` pero esa misma ya esta siendo empleada con otro fin, lo cual me llevaría a tener que hacer un `echo` pero se supone que he leído que no se debe imprimir nada directamente en los métodos de las clases

Aclaro que NO estoy buscando opiniones ni opciones o recomendaciones de cuando usar cada uno, lo único que busco aclarar es lo ya antes mencionado

Comment: Para responde a tu segunda pregunta, es necesario que expliques que esperas que suceda, porque no esta claro cual es el resultado final.

Comment: ¿Será [algo como esto](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f73c0edf412d78127d5c9cad53830caee7e1d050) es lo que buscas lograr?

Comment: @Marcos hola te agradezco la respuesta y lamento responder tan tarde, permiteme revisar y te comento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El encadenamiento ([`chaining`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)) se basa en que **al resultado** de ejecutar una acción, **aplicar un método o función propio de este**.

Así sucesivamente hasta que **el resultado obtenido no provea dicha "funcionalidad"**.

---

En tu caso, al hacer `return $this`, estas devolviendo la referencia de la instancia de `Person`, permitiendo así el encadenando a los métodos propios y heredados de dicha clase.

Luego pierdes la capacidad de continuar el encadenamiento al hacer `return $name;` (*En los ejemplos `$name` es una cadena y en `PHP` carecen de métodos propios*).

---

> ¿Por qué se retorna lo antes mencionado en cada ejemplo?

```
return $this
return new static
```

Al hacer `return $this` o `return new static` estas proporcionando la capacidad de hacer encadenamiento sobre la instancia misma.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
//Un ejemplo básico de uso de clases estáticas PHP
//Para que vayas comprendiendo

Class Cadena{
    //Declaro una variable
    public static $str1 = "Mi cadena 1";
    public static $str2 = "Mi cadena 2";

    //Creo un metodo de la clase
    public static function mayusculas($str){
        return strtoupper($str);
    }
    public static function minusculas($str){
        return strtolower($str);
    }   
}

//Uso de la clase

echo Cadena::mayusculas("hola mundo")."<br>";
echo Cadena::minusculas("HOLA MUNDO")."<br>";

echo Cadena::$str1."<br>"; //Acceder a una variable publica de la clase estática
echo Cadena::$str2."<br>"; //Acceder a una variable publica de la clase estática`introducir el código aquí`
```

Comment: Se te agradece la respuesta, pero no estoy preguntando sobre declaración o como acceder a métodos estáticos(lo cual ya conozco), mi pregunta si revisas de nuevo va orientada al uso de `return new static` y `return $this` y como retornar valores personalizados sin que esto afecte lo antes mencionado

Answer (score 1):

He estado buscando al respecto y encontré que es una técnica llamada **static factory method**, **lo cual por cierto no es un patrón de diseño de software así que NO confundir con el patrón FACTORY METHOD**

Lo cual ayuda por ejemplo para no requerir directamente de un método constructor `__construct()` para inicializar los valores que serán asignados a las propiedades de la clase.

En esta parte:

```
public static function  userType($type)
    {
        return new Person($type);
    }
```

Entonces ocurre lo siguiente:

- Genera una instancia de la propia clase que la contiene dentro del método `userType` el cual recibe como parámetro la propiedad `$type`, esta misma instancia será invocada una vez que se haga el llamado: `Clase::algunMetodo....`
- Una vez que la clase intenta acceder a este método estático, el mismo va a requerir el valor con el cual va a inicializar dicha propiedad
- El segundo método llamado `myName` estaría actuando como un `getter` el cual me va a servir para acceder al valor ya que es el que tiene la instrucción de retorno `return` y en concencuencia poder mostrar el resultado

Por cierto tengo un error en el llamado al método `myName` pues al ser estático debería ser con `::` y no con `->`

Consulte el libro *Effective Java* de *Joshua Bloch* para acercarme de mejor manera al concepto como tal y poder llevarlo al código

En resumidas cuentas al menos *así lo entendí*

Comment: A mi me parece que `return $this` tiene mejor rendimiento que `return new static` ya que con el primero devuelves la referencia del mismo objeto, pero con la segunda forma se crea un nuevo objeto copia debido a `new` en cada llamada, lo cual me parece innecesario y afecta al rendimiento

Comment: Ademas de eso, si se matiene una variable con referencia la instancia inicial, todos los datos configurados a travez del `chaining` solo existen en la última instancia creada y la variable original presentaria errores.